# German Playing Card Suits?

Tags: symbols, packages

Traditional German playing cards use a different set of suit symbols from what's used basically everywhere else. Instead of the usual four suits (Clubs, Spades, Hearts, Diamonds), parts of Germany use these:

[image] (credit to Wikipedia)

I haven't been able to find anything even remotely related to this regarding LaTeX symbols, especially since Google things I want to buy German latex gimp suits....

Does anyone know of any packages I can load to achieve this?

Comment: If you have the images, you can wrap an `\includegrapghics` in a custom command like `\newcommand{\herzen}{\includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{herzen.png}}`

Comment: @DG' yeah that's the last resort if nothing else exists

Comment: why "last resort"? if you find a package that's probably what it does internally. especially if you want color any font version would be very limited in choice

Comment: There are two packages I am aware of (you can find them searching for "poker" on CTAN), one using PSTricks, one using Ti*k*Z. They both support "standard" French suits, but especially the latter basically just inserts images when and where appropriate and should be easy to adapt to a new set of images. (It does support a wide variety out of the box, like UNO cards etc.) Unfortunately the documentation is only available in French.

Comment: @Ingmar card suits are also included in amsmath afaik `\heartsuit` `\clubsuit` etc. I use them all the time. I'll look into the one you suggested